# Laravel eloquent issue with constructor

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, eloquent

I have a model which contains many methods.

```
class UserModel extends Eloquent{

    private $active;

    function __construct() {        
    $this->active = Config::get('app.ActiveFlag');
    }

    protected $table = 'User';
    protected $fillable = array('usr_ID', 'username');

    public function method1(){
      //use $active here
    }

    public function method2(){
      //use $active here
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
$user = new UserModel($inputall);
$user->save();
```

Without constructor, it works fine. However, with constructor it doesn't save the user (the query which is generated doesn't have any fill attributes or values). The query is as follows:

```
 insert into User() values();
```

Any inputs please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well yes, that's because you override the Eloquent constructor which is responsible to fill the model with values when an array is passed. You have to pass them along to the parent with `parent::__construct()`:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array()){
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->active = Config::get('app.ActiveFlag');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Missed out it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Your model's constructor doesn't accept any parameters - empty `()`, and you are creating new instance of UserModel in your controller adding `$inputall` as a parameter.

Try to refactor your contructor according to this:

```
class UserModel extends Eloquent {
    public function __construct($attributes = array())  {
        parent::__construct($attributes);
        // Your additional code here
    }
}
```

(Answer based on [other Eloquent contructor question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888698/constructors-on-classes-extending-eloquent))